# The file \"/tmp/phpw1sHMV\" cannot be opened - Tengo el problema al cargar archivos

Tags: php, laravel

tengo el siguiente problema:

```
"message": "The file \"/tmp/phpw1sHMV\" cannot be opened: ",
    "exception": "RuntimeException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/develop/apicliente/api-recibos/vendor/nyholm/psr7/src/Factory/Psr17Factory.php",
```

el problema surge cuando realizo una carga masiva de documentos a partir de 510 documentos, mientras que 509 e inferiores hacen que el proceso sea correcto para mí, cambie varios datos en el php ini, como: la cantidad máxima de archivos, el peso y otros factores y confirme que el plataforma esta para subir mil archivos o mas. también edite el nginx aumentando el max_file_uploads.

Tambien me fije en permisos y no funciono, que conste que en el local me funciona bien en el servidor me salta ese error no tengo idea como solucionarlo.

Comment: Hiciste algún debug para confirmar que el request llega completo? Cómo los envías a los archivos?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ que seria un debug? los archivos los envio a un punto de montura con permisos de carpeta y con el resto de archivos no me da ningun problema.

Comment: [Debug](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depuraci%C3%B3n_de_programas) sería depuración en español, ¿podrías revisar si el request llega completo o llega truncado hasta donde sea que manejes el request?. Te preguntaba "cómo envías los archivos", y me refiería a si los envías en un formulario, en un input cada uno, o cómo los envías. Y también sería útil saber cómo lo manejas a eso, si todo el proceso es durante el request, o lo envía a una cola, o estás haciendo alguna otra cosa...

Comment: También revisar los logs de nginx, ya que tal vez antes de llegar a php o laravel, el servidor es el que te está limitando eso

Comment: sabes que recursos tiene el servidor, puedes modificar el .ini o nginx pero si los recursos no dan es imposible

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ los archivos los envios en un input todos juntos.

Comment: si los recursos del servidor es lo ultimo que deberia ver pero no tuve tiempo. tengo 12 de ram si te sirve  @NicolasAldana

Comment: Te sugiero leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego presiona en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/530164/edit) y agrega un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de tu código para que podamos ayudarte.